# Правильное оформление пояснения

Tags: пунктуация

Развивая идею подобия инновационных процессов и промышленных процессов производства рыночного продукта, можно ввести еще один новый термин — «логистика инноваций», как аналог известному термину «логистика производственных процессов».

Мне кажется, что в этом предложении вместо второй запятой должно стоять тире, так как если убрать вставку, никаких запятых не требуется. Но, может быть, последнюю часть предложения можно рассматривать как уточнение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше оставить предложенный вариант:

Развивая идею подобия инновационных процессов и промышленных процессов производства рыночного продукта, можно ввести еще один новый термин — «логистика инноваций», как аналог известному термину «логистика производственных процессов».

Тогда мы обособляем с помощью тире два приложения, причем второе приложение является оборотом с союзом КАК (значение уподобления, союз КАК можно убрать) и поясняет первое приложение.

Comment: Т. е. _термин_ - это определяемое слово, а _логистика инноваций_ и _аналог_ - это приложения? И соответственно, без вставки запятая тоже будет нужна? Спасибо. Про приложения думала, но не была уверена.

Comment: Да, мне кажется, что так правильно, к тому же  графика текста (а также интонация)  позволяют ясно и однозначно понять содержание высказывания..

Comment: Абсолютно вами согласен, Вера.